# How can I safely give MySQL DELETE power to my script?

Tags: php, mysql, security

I seem to have painted myself into a corner with my efforts to run a secure PHP / MySQL site. I created a MySQL user that has minimal powers to run the site, so no DELETE privilege, amongst others, and it all works fine. Recently, I have added extensions that look for excessive users taking up too many resources and I ban them for 24 / 48 hours based on IP address. Not perfect, but it deters the average user from too much abuse.

That works fine too. The issue is that my list of 24 hour bans is in a table that grows at an alarming rate. Ideally I'd have a script that deletes everything in the table whose timestamp is older than the ban period as they are no longer needed. Then I could run that script from a cron job.

The problem is that that script fails because the user account credentials don't include DELETE privileges. If I create an extra user who does have DELETE, aren't I undermining the security of the whole site? Is there a middle way or other solution, or just some precautions that I can take. What's the best way to resolve this conflict?

Comment: So you think the only way having a "secure" site is having nobody with delete priviledges?

Comment: @juergen d No, I didn't say any such thing. I don't speak in absolutes and never use phrases like "the only way'. Indeed, my phraseology was noticably tentative. I hold my beliefs lightly. You should hold on more tightly to what people actually say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole point of having separate accounts is so that you can give each account the privileges appropriate to its duties. If you need to delete things, you obviously have to create an account with DELETE privileges. But that doesn't undermine everything, because all the other accounts are still restricted.

Furthermore, this account doesn't have to have widespread `DELETE` privileges. You can just grant it the privilege to `DELETE` in the table that lists bans. Although if you try to get too fine-grained with permissions, you're likely to drive yourself crazy.

```
GRANT DELETE on dbname.bans TO deleter@localhost;
```

Finally, if you have an account that has `UPDATE` privileges, it's not so bad to allow it `DELETE` privileges as well. Because even if it can't delete rows, it could still totally mess up your data by replacing rows with garbage.

Comment: Thank you for that. I didn't know I could tie DELETE permission to a single table. I haven't been able to find out much about that. I wonder if you know of an online resource that might give practical guidence for beginners? It sounds ideal as it wouldn't be a catastropie if that entire table got wiped, accidentally or maliciously. I follow your logic about UPDATE too. Thank you.

Comment: Have you looked at the syntax of GRANT? When you grant permission, you say `GRANT <privileges> ON dbname.tablename TO username`. You can replace `tablename` with `*` to mean all tables in the database, but you can also specify a single table.

Comment: Thank you - I will look into that and impliment it if possible (I am limited to what I can do through my ISP's control panel). Thank you Barmar.

Comment: This is not the only solution (although it is presented as such). You can specify that a stored procedure runs with different privileges than the user invoking it ( SQL SECURITY { DEFINER | INVOKER } ). The invoker still needs execute privilege.

Answer (score 0):

If in any case you don't want to use the DELETE privilege to any mysql users in you application I would prefer to use the UPDATE. Any time your application scripts find a user needs ban instead of writing to a new record, will search for the first banned user with smallest timestamp (oldest banned user) and UPDATE it's values.

This is the best I can think.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful response Dimitriadis. However I think Barmar has a point about UPDATE being potentially just as destructive as DELETE. I appreciate your contribution anyway.